# I am unable to launch or uninstall Sosumi

Tags: software-center, uninstall

Recently I was uninstalling Sosumi from my laptop, so I could get a fresh install of macOS to give it more storage. What ended up happening is, the software center crashed at 75%, Sosumi never got removed from my app list. Now when I click on it to launch it, nothing happens, and when I try to finish uninstalling it through the software center, (as I don't know the command or the full package name to do it through the terminal) it just instantly stops trying to uninstall it when I click remove. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue, but succeeded by running the following command:

```
sudo snap remove -purge sosumi
```

Comment: it's actually `--purge`

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command in a terminal. It will prompt you for you password.

`snap remove sosumi`